# Source Tree GIT - How to cancel a merge

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

Started a merge between branches in source tree and changed my mind. Wanted to redo the merge but am getting the error when starting the merge again :

> "fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).Please,
>   commit your changes before you merge."

[image: Error]

I cannot see any un-committed files but when clicking the "Commit", I get the previous merge changes.

How do I cancel this merge ?

Comment: (Prefer posting code and errors as text in your questions)

Answer (score 52):

You are in the merge process.
If you need to abort the merge, You need to get out of the merge by using `git merge --abort`.

If not do a git status `git status` to figure out what the conflicts and changes are and then commit those changes to continue with the merge.

Comment: Thanks!! that solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

Since you have uncommitted code you can revert back to your `HEAD`

`> git reset --hard HEAD`

Answer (score 3):

From this [Atlassian doc resource](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/How-do-I-revert-abort-a-merge-using-source-tree/qaq-p/350099):

> Hit 'Revert' on the toolbar, but then click on the 'Reset All' tab and use that. This will reset the merge metadata too.

By the way, you might handle this from the Git command line using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: Reset and revert are different things. Can you make sure that source tree’s revert is exactly that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox "Revert" in SourceTree is not a Git revert.  It is more like an SVN revert, which is a reset in Git.  Check the doc link in my answer.

Comment: Of course you know the difference (I shouldn’t have said contrary). I’m not sure it’s a good thing that they mix up the terminology like that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, it's very irritating, especially when you're trying to help someone and they say "revert," but really what is happening is a reset.